# executing a bash process that execute npm from c# code

Tags: c#, bash, .net-core

I am writing a c# program and I want to run (npm install) and (npm run build) from the c# code.
I tried

```
public static Boolean BuildNpm()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("start process method?");
            var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory="../../frontend/";
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";
            proc.Start();
            //npm install
            //npm run build
            //exit
            proc.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine("Done?");
            return (proc.ExitCode == 0) ? true : false;
        }
```

I was able to create a shell that ask for command and I add the commands I want but I want the commands in the program automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to run bash to run the commands? Shouldn't it work to run `npm` directly from your program?

```
public static Boolean BuildNpm()
{
    Console.WriteLine("start process method?");
    var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory="../../frontend/";
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "/path/to/npm";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "install";
    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "run build";
    Console.WriteLine("Done?");
    return (proc.ExitCode == 0) ? true : false;
}
```

You should add some error handling if either execution of `npm` fails, as well.

Comment: I tried to do that but couldn't find the path to npm

Comment: If you run `which npm` that should return the path to npm. You can hard code that for now, but you'll need a better solution if you want other people to run your program as well.